# Unable to display list of active users in sails and node, no errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I have a table on my `index.ejs` file that should display the current logged in users (via appending table rows). Here is how it's built:

```
            <table id="status-table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Player</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Score</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
```

In my `user.js` model (file route: assets/js/user.js), I create this function:

```
addUser: function(user) {

            var found = false;

            // Check if the user is already in the table
            $('#status-table tr').each(function() {
                var hasUser = $(this).attr('id');

                if (hasUser !== undefined && ('user-' + user.id == hasUser)) {
                    found = true;
                }
            });

            if (!found) {
                var $table = $('#status-table');
                var ready = (user.id == me.id) ? '<button type="button" id="changeStatus" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">change</button>' : '';
                var row = '<tr id="user-'+user.id+'"><td class="name" data-avatar="'+user.avatar+'">'+user.name+'</td><td><img class="flag" src="http://api.hostip.info/flag.php?ip='+user.ip+'" width="20" height="14" alt=""><span class="status" data-status="'+user.status+'">'+user.status+'</span>'+ready+'</td><td class="score">'+user.score+'</td></tr>';
                $table.append(row);

                QW_MODULES.chat.updateUI();
            }
        }
```

This function should fire because in my `app.js` I call an init to that entire `user.js` file on "socket connection".

```
io.socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {
    QW_MODULES.user.init();
});
```

What could be going wrong to not fire this function? I'm not receiving any errors on login/sign up.

Edit: Here is my user function that gets init'd:

```
var QW_MODULES = (function (modules, $) {

    "use strict";

    var self;

    var user = {

        init: function() {

            self = this;
        },

        // Add a user to the list of available users to play with
        addUser: function(user) {

            var found = false;

            // Check if the user is already in the table
            $('#status-table tr').each(function() {
                var hasUser = $(this).attr('id');

                if (hasUser !== undefined && ('user-' + user.id == hasUser)) {
                    found = true;
                }
            });

            if (!found) {
                var $table = $('#status-table');
                var ready = (user.id == me.id) ? '<button type="button" id="changeStatus" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">change</button>' : '';
                var row = '<tr id="user-'+user.id+'"><td class="name" data-avatar="'+user.avatar+'">'+user.name+'</td><td><img class="flag" src="http://api.hostip.info/flag.php?ip='+user.ip+'" width="20" height="14" alt=""><span class="status" data-status="'+user.status+'">'+user.status+'</span>'+ready+'</td><td class="score">'+user.score+'</td></tr>';
                $table.append(row);

                QW_MODULES.chat.updateUI();
            }
        },

        // Remove a user from the table of available users to play with, by sending
        // either a user object or a user ID.
        removeUser: function(user) {

            // Get the user's ID.
            var id = user.id || user;
            var userName = $('#user-'+id).text();

            // Remove the corresponding element from the users table
            var userEl = $('#user-'+id).remove();

            QW_MODULES.chat.updateUI();
        },

        // Add multiple users to the users list.
        updateUserList: function(users) {

            $('#status-table tbody tr').remove();

            users.forEach(function(user) {

                if ((typeof user.id === 'undefined') || (user.status === 'offline') || (typeof me === 'undefined')) {
                    return;
                }

                self.addUser(user);
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: please show as the `init()` and `updateUI()`functions, also check if the `connect` callback is even accessed.

Comment: Hi @ju_ thanks for the response, I added my user function to my question, I'm not sure how I would check for the connect callback though, could you go into more detail on that?